# Limit problem calculating directional derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given $f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2$, find the directional derivative at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the direction of the unit vector $\vec u$.

I am experiencing some strange behavior with the Limit function. I quit the kernel and re-evaluate the notebook, but here is what happens.

```
Clear[f, x0, y0, a, b, u];
f[x_, y_] = 1 - x^2 - y^2;
a = Cos[Pi/3];
b = Sin[Pi/3];
u = {a, b};
{x0, y0} = .2 u;
```

Then, the limit definition is:
$$D_uf(x_0,y_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h a, y_0+h b)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$
However, I am getting a strange answer.

```
Limit[(f[x0 + h a, y0 + h b] - f[x0, y0])/h, h -> 0]
```

Output:

```
\[Infinity]
```

Now, consider:

```
Table[(f[x0 + h a, y0 + h b] - f[x0, y0])/
  h, {h, {1., .1, .01, .001, 0.0001}}]
```

Output:

```
{-1.4, -0.5, -0.41, -0.401, -0.4001}
```

Another definition is $D_uf(x_0,y_0)=\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\cdot \vec u$.

```
Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}].u;
% /. {x -> x0, y -> y0}
```

Output:

```
-0.4
```

See? The correct answer is $-0.4$, but the limit definition is not working for some reason? I hope this isn't a typo or some silly thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing exact and machine numbers in the definition of the function `f`. The machine numbers create a small nonzero constant term in the numerator of the `Limit`, which is the cause of the infinite result as you divide by `h` and take `h -> 0`.

The fix is to use `{x0,y0}= u/5` instead of `0.2`.

However, if you *do* need to work with machine numbers, you could do this:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

{x0,y0}= .2u;

NLimit[(f[x0 + h a, y0 + h b] - f[x0, y0])/h, h -> 0]

(* ==> -0.4 *)
```

Numerical limits as done in `NLimit` account for the presence of the kind of roundoff errors that you're seeing.

Comment: Also, you should use `SetDelayed` in your function definition: `f[x_,y_] := 1 - x^2 - y^2`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer That's true, unless `x` and `y` are `Clear`ed beforehand.

Comment: @Jens. Thanks for the quick answer. I performed each of your suggestions and both work, but this is a bizarre event. I have never experienced this before. This probably will be rare with the students, but when it happens, oh my goodness. Tough one to explain.

Comment: @David, the issue of finite precision numbers giving misleading answers is actually quite common on this page, at least recently ;) At least for "analytic" type stuff where no approximations are wanted one should always first try with exact numbers.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer. I am currently writing on notebook introducing the directional derivative for my students in the fall. I think this event, though bizarre, is actually (as you say) a fortunate event, because this example is going into the notebook with an explanation to the students on how to handle the situation. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Looking at  the result of `Simplify[(f[x0 + h a, y0 + h b] - f[x0, y0])/h]` should be revealing.